# spring boot required a bean of type 'com.aluguelsala.config.JwtProperties' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm facing a problem initializing my Spring Boot application, and I'm receiving the following error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.aluguelsala.config.JwtProperties required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
```

I have a JwtProperties class annotated with @Component and @ConfigurationProperties("jwt").

The TokenService class is trying to inject JwtProperties into the constructor.
My application.yml file has the following settings for jwt:

```
jwt:
key: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
access-token-expiration: 3600000
refresh-token-expiration: 86400000

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties

@ConfigurationProperties("jwt")
data class JwtProperties(
val key: String,
val accessTokenExpiration: Long,
val refreshTokenExpiration: Long,
)

@Service
class TokenService (
jwtProperties: JwtProperties

){

 private val secretKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(
jwtProperties.key.toByteArray()
)

 fun generate(
userDetails : UserDetails,
expirationDate: Date,
additionalClaims: Map<String, Any> = emptyMap()
 ):String =
Jwts.builder()
  .claims()
  .subject(userDetails.username)
  .issuedAt(Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
  .expiration(expirationDate)
  .add(additionalClaims)
  .and()
  .signWith(secretKey)
  .compact()

  fun isValid(token: String, userDetails: UserDetails): Boolean {
  val email = extractEmail(token)
  return userDetails.username == email && !isExpired(token)
 }


  fun extractEmail(token: String): String? =
  getAllClaims(token)
  .subject

 fun isExpired(token: String): Boolean =
  getAllClaims(token)
  .expiration
  .before(Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))

 private fun getAllClaims(token: String): Claims {
val parser = Jwts.parser()
  .verifyWith(secretKey)
  .build()
 return parser
   .parseSignedClaims(token)
  .payload
 }
```

}

Steps I've already tried:

Check whether the JwtProperties and TokenService classes are in the same package or in subordinate packages.

Confirm that the @Component annotation is present in JwtProperties.

Comment: I really suggest you to read/check (https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/spring-boot-configurationproperties)